# Python Beautiful Soup Returns Nonetype

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to develop a program that can grab runes for a specific champion in League of Legends.
And here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup





url = 'https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/zh/champions/builds/darius'

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
tables = soup.find('div',class_ = 'img-align-block') 
print(tables)
```

And here is the original HTML File:

```
<img src="//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8010.png" alt="征服者" tooltip="<itemname><img src=&quot;//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8010.png&quot; width=&quot;24&quot; height=&quot;24&quot; alt=&quot;征服者&quot; /> 征服者</itemname><br/><br/>基礎攻擊或技能在命中敵方英雄時獲得 2 層征服者效果，持續 6 秒，每層效果提供 2-5 適性之力。 最多可以疊加 10 次。遠程英雄每次普攻只會提供 1 層效果。<br><br>在疊滿層數後，你對英雄造成的 15% 傷害會轉化為對自身的回復效果（遠程英雄則為 8%）。" height="36" width="36" class="requireTooltip">
```

I am not able to by any chance access this part and parse it nor find the IMG src. However, I can browse through this on their website. 
How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The part you are interested in is not in the HTML. You can double check by searching:

```py
soup.prettify()
```

Probably parts of the website are loaded with JavaScript, so you could use code that opens a browser and visit that page. For example, you could use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)  # give the website some time to load
page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
tables = soup.find('div', class_='img-align-block') 
print(tables)
```

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The website uses JavaScript processing, so you need to use Selenium or another scraping tool that supports JS loading.

Comment: I will definitely look at that. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `User-Agent` on the `headers` of your request, without it, the website sends a different content, i.e.:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/zh/champions/builds/darius'
h = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=h).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img', {"class" : 'mainPicture'})
for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

---

```
//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8010.png
//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8010.png
//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8230.png
//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8230.png
//cdn2.leagueofgraphs.com/img/perks/10.8/64/8230.png
```

---

Notes:

- [Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/b3a10a94e0)
- If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping, This inspires me a lot.